# Unable to see USB device in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, vmware, vmware-fusion

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 with VMWare Fusion 8.5.1

Before upgrading to vmware fusion 8.5.1, everything was ok. Now when I connect the USB device, I can see the following logs in `dmesg`

```
[   36.420842] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[   36.559698] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1f75, idProduct=0916
[   36.559702] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[   36.559703] usb 1-1: Product: SSK SFD201 USB Device
[   36.559704] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: SSK
[   36.559705] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: xxx
```

But no device file is created, I've tried to list `/dev/sd*` but only the local hdd is found.

Any ideas?

Attached output of several commands,

```
# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1f75:0916 Innostor Technology Corporation
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0e0f:0008 VMware, Inc.
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0003 VMware, Inc. Virtual Mouse
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
# ls /dev/sd*
/dev/sda  /dev/sda1  /dev/sda2  /dev/sda5
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay. This is really stupid.

I've removed wireless packages like `wireless-regdb iw` in the VM, because I don't need it.

However, it also removed packages like `linux-image-extra-4.4.0-47-generic`, which contains the `usb_storage` module.

Yeah, the USB is recognized when I reinstall that package and load the usb storage module.